# Python Test in CircleCi - Unicode Error when working with files

Tags: python, ubuntu, unicode, encoding, circleci

This is a weird error that I am facing ONLY when running Python tests in CircleCI Docker mode.  They work perfectly fine when running on local Docker machine.  The only difference between Docker in CircleCI and local is the Ubuntu Version (14.04-CircleCi vs 16.04-Local).  Could this be the reason for this issue?

My code:

```
some_file = path + '/some_file_name'

for line in some_file:
  sys.stdout.write(line.replace("replace_this", 
                      variable_that_may_have_unicode_chars))

updated_file = io.open(some_file, 'r')
file_contents = updated_file.read()
```

This is a minimal example that throws the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position
>   1: ordinal not in range(128)

If I use the encoding at one place, it starts throwing errors at other places where it worked earlier.

Comment: So is the error thrown on the last line?

Comment: Error is thrown while both, reading and writing.

Comment: What Docker image are you using? What version of CircleCI? If 2.0, which executor? Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: CircleCI 1.0.  Docker image is provided by CircleCI.